# How to remove event listener of react-navigation in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I want to detect focus change on naviagtion in React Native.
I am using class components but now days RN community flooded with functional component .

Here is the snippet from @react-naviagtion

```
function Profile({ navigation }) {
    React.useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
        // Screen was focused
        // Do something
      });
  
      return unsubscribe;
    }, [navigation]);
  
    return (
        <>
            <Text>tedtx</Text>
        </>
    );
  }
```

I have used in class component and it works well no memory leak warning yet but I don't know if this is a way to do or not.

```
    componentDidMount(){
        
        this.state.focusListener = this.props.nav.navigation.addListener('focus',()=>{
            log('route ',this.props)
        })
         // should I return here
    }
   componentWillUnmount(){
       // or should i something here?
       // this.props.nav.navigation.removeListener(this.state.focusEvent)
      //above does not give error but not removing listener
   }
```

I noticed that reloading the metro remove listeners.
As I save the file (Hot Reloading) and try to invoke the the listeners on focus it actually increases. It increase by one each time I hot reload. It seems that listeners are not getting removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> you can try this

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this._unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // do something
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unsubscribe();
  }

  render() {
    // Content of the component
  }
}
```

react navigation events: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/

Answer (score 2):

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.focusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus',() => {
    log('route ',this.props);
  });
  // should I return here
  // nothing to return
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.focusListener();
}
```

Yes, most of the examples show usage in functional component but there is an example in [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events) showing how to setup/ remove navigation listeners in class component

Answer (score 2):

I did this with with function components and hooks...

```js
  const [canGoBack, setCanGoBack] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const listenerUnsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      setCanGoBack(navigation.canGoBack())
    })
    return () => listenerUnsubscribe()
  }, [navigation])
```